# Using VIM's regex to convert MM/DD/YYYY to proper date ("June 4, 1999") for end user consumption

Tags: regex, vim

Here are my parameters:

- I need to change MM/DD/YYYY (MM-DD-YYYY, MM.DD.YYYY, etc) to MONTH,
  DAY YEAR. Eg: 1/29/2001 => January 29, 2001.
- It's for what will be a    human read output. I need to make this
  change many times, on several computers. Previous person tasked
  with this had been doing it by hand.
- I can depend on VIM (because    it is on a thumb drive) but nothing
  else being on a computer when I get to it.

The challenge: make a regular expression to fix this quickly, on a per computer basis.

This is what I have (using #'s as delimiters):

```
%s#\([1-9]\|1[012]\)[- /.]\([1-9]\|[12][0-9]\|3[01]\)[- /.]\([19\|20]\d\d\)#UGLYPART \2, \3#g
```

The search part works correctly, as I get \2 and \3 in the correct place. I know the UGLYPART will use \1, and then some sort of evaluation like:

```
((\1)\=(1\|2\|3\|4\|5\|6\|7\|8\|9\|10\|11\|12)(January\|February\|March\|April\|May\|June\|July\|August\|September\|October\|November\|December))
```

Except that it will work.

Does anyone have any insight? I feel like I'm about 90% there. Or am I asking too much of Vim's regex?

Comment: Why is `MM/DD/YYYY` not proper "for end user consumption"?

Comment: @JackManey Maybe because `MM` is before `DD` (or because you can’t be sure whether `MM` is before or after `DD`)? It is distracting: most of time day is more significant information then month and thus should be put at visually better reachable place: at the start or, at least, at the end of the date. Definitely not in the *middle*.

Comment: ZyX is correct. This date format is what the end user specifically requested -- they are nontechnical, and this is the most _explicit_ possible way to show them the date.

Comment: Vim can execute python code. I'd make use of that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use vim in "line edit" (ex) mode, using -e. 
Then  give it a **file** of edit commands.

Assume these commands are in date.ex:

```
g/\([0-9][0-9]*\)[./-]1[./-]\([012][0-9][0-9]*\)/s//January \1, \2/
g/\([0-9][0-9]*\)[./-]2[./-]\([012][0-9][0-9]*\)/s//February \1, \2/
g/\([0-9][0-9]*\)[./-]3[./-]\([012][0-9][0-9]*\)/s//March \1, \2/
... etc ...
w
q
```

then invoke vim as

```
vim -e -S date.ex foo
```

where foo is the file you want to edit. SO yoy can have a shell script to run this across all the files in a file system.

Comment: I had forgotten that VI can invoke ex. This works well! I'm going to create a bunch of scripts to really shape up these files -- each one is full of inconsistencies.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should use `\=`, but it is used in another fashion:

```
%s#\v([1-9]|1[012])[\- /.]([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.]((19|20)\d\d)#\=strftime('%B', 28*24*60*60*submatch(1)).' '.submatch(2).', '.submatch(3)#g
```

Note: `[]` is a collection, thus `[19\|20]` you written here is treated as `1`, `9`, `\`, `|`, `2` or `0`. You should use `\(19\|20\)`. And use `\v` to avoid unneeded escapes.

Note 2: I do not want to write a list of months. You can see that 28th day of year is January, 28*2=56th is February, 28*3=84th is March and so on up to December, so you can use `strftime()` function and the fact that timestamp `0` (in seconds) is 1st January (not of the current year, but this does not matter). It will depend on locale though: in english locale `strftime('%B', 28*24*60*60*1)` will output “January”, but on my system it outputs “Январь”.

Note 3: `\=` must always be on the very first position in replacement string.

Comment: ZyX -- this does the trick too! I had no known about strftime(). I'll have to look at VIMs other functions. Thanks for turning me on to this!

Comment: @CRS. You can have a list of months and use `list_var_name[submatch(1)-1]` (or even `["January", "February", ...][submatch(1)-1]`), but, as I said, I do not want to define it as there is already `strftime()`.